# Issues setting up routing for one IP address to specific network interface

Tags: linux, networking, router, ip, routing

For one IP address ( aaa.bb.c.d ) I need to connect via eth1 not eth0 ( which was default one and was suppose to remain a default one but I don't think it did after eth1 was added.

Last rule I've added myself using command `route add -host 172.27.4.213 dev eth1` <- And Im guessing it is incorrect to.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-2eeb687f709e
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-0971950c62b2
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-c4f8472e3ea8
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-197f22a151b6
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d1df5bfeb2d6
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e00c82e13142
aaa.bb.c.d      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1

$ ip a show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:b5:7d:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.27/16 brd 10.0.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feb5:7d7b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip a show eth1
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:b5:7d:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.170/16 brd 10.0.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feb5:7d85/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.27
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    dns-nameservers 10.0.0.2

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: What you have configured does not follow best practices.  If you are trying to have eth0 and eth1 in the same group they should be bonded together.  If ot, they should be in different subnets.   What are you trying to achieve with this setup, and why does this IP address need to be accessed through eth1 not eth0, and is it directly connected ?

Comment: It has PostgreSQL database which I need to connect to. eth1 was given to me by IT ( virtual server ) eth1 is allowed to connect to that db server and eth0 isn't. And that server is available on that IP I'm trying to redirect to eth1. I've added /etc/network/interfaces to the main post

Comment: Get IT to fix the IP addressing issues (they could be DHCP related) on your network and the problem will magically go away. eth1 should not be in the same network as eth0 in this configuration.

Comment: Btw, everything is going out eth1 according to your routing table.

Comment: Hmm. What you mean by saying network? :x, sorry I'm a noob like that. Is it because broadcast is the same?

Comment: The IP addresses for both eth0 and eth1 are in the same subnet - ie 10.0.0.0/16 - that means that they need to be connected to the same set of switches, and there is little point (except a bit of redundancy, sort-of - but this is better handled with channel bonding).   I posit that there is an error here, and either the netmasks should be 255.255.255.0 or there is something else going on - either way, this is a problem for a network administrator to fix.